# Coherent read-only view of a database

Tags: sql, database

I would like to perform a select query that returns a lot of data on a database. Said database forces me to split my queries in chunks of 10000 results with offset+limit. While I iterate over these chunks, someone else updates the database which could in some cases make the db return the same row multiple times. I handle that by a post-processing filter that removes rows with duplicate ids but I wonder if there is a way to build a set of sql queries that allows me to obtain a coherent view of the database across multiple select statements. i.e., BEGIN+COMMIT but for select.

Did I mention that I am not an sql person ?

Comment: Please state what database you are using and the code on your receiving part (whatever language that is). I suspect that most DBs are able to deliver more results when they are called in streaming mode, but that can't be said for sure without the information.

Comment: In fact, I have to confess that this problem occured while talking to a sparql virtuoso server. All of the sql databases I ever used handle this case nicely by just streaming the data to me until I get it all.

Comment: Well, as this is a commercial project, have you tried asking the hotline? I mean, it should provide you with a solution in a way (be it in form of transactions or streaming) and the developers will know best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not:

Order them by ID, get the first 10000, get the LAST id.

Second time around filter on greater that LAST id, getting the next 10000.

Do the same till your done

```
Select top(10000) * from Table order by id
```

get the last id

```
Select top(10000) * from Table where id> LAST order by id
```

LAST of course substituted by a number

Very low level, but should solve problem and eliminate duplicates

Comment: what happens if a row is removed while I am looking in the database and its row id is reused ?

Comment: you wont get the "new" version before next time you run the thing. row ids aught to be unique, but maybe not in your case.... is there a timestamp you can use for the sorting? Thus getting new ones last. You will have to cope with the same ID issue again though...

Comment: @mathieu that function should work if ID is unique. If it is not (can be reused) then you should generate an ID that is unique and use this.